# Which Auth is usfull in Laravel / VueJS project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication

I am planning a small project and have a question about authentication. I would like to implement the site with Laravel 8. However, as soon as the user has successfully logged in, he should be directed to the user dashboard. The User Dashboard should be a pure VueJS Single Page Application.

Now my question. Which auth should I use here? Session or token for the whole site or is both possible and useful?

If I use the token auth variant, for example, then I can protect the Vue app very well but I cannot access the user information outside the Vue app. For example, the current profile picture of the user should appear in the navbar and not only in the vue app but also on the landing page, contact page etc.

How can I do this and what will be the best practice and thanks for your help!

Comment: it's depend site is full single page application or part of this single page

Comment: @KamleshPaul Only one part - the user dashboard

Comment: then use seesion auth

Comment: @KamleshPaul. And how i protected the api which deliver the SPA witch userdata?

Comment: if route is protected by sesssion you can call api only you need csrf_token which for post req. which you can get from html

Answer (score 0):

Use token based Authentication
(Laravel Passport)

Comment: please add explain why it is solution ?

Comment: if you are installing vuejs with laravel (laravel ui) then it is good to use session based authentication(Laravel Sanctum).

But here you are using 2 different one is laravel and other is vuejs.
So use laravel Passport it will be helpful and easy to do it.

Comment: I will try with JWT. @HariShankarSingh: What you do thing about JWT?

Comment: @MaikLowrey You can try with that also.

Answer (score 0):

Use Token-based authentication system.

In this way, you'll be able to manage the entire application UI and role checking in the frontend only. I would rather prefer to go with JWT **[[https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/]](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/)**. It's easy to use and the documentation is pretty good. It's even supported by Lumen also. If you wish to integrate any micro-service in your application future, then it's available in Lumen micro-service also.

Comment: if i will use an spa the answear would be ok. but in my case i want to have access to auth()->user()  outside of vue. and i cant imagen to do that with token based auth!? or am I mistaken?

Comment: Then, you can try Laravel "Sanctum" package for session-based authentication. But the only thing you need to be aware of that it will only work if the Vue.js and Laravel application runs on the same base origin. For that use, you have to maintain Vue.js and Laravel in the same application repository. Sanctum: "https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum". Reference Repository: "https://github.com/tridibdawn/Coffee-Shop-Laravel-Vue-SPA"

Comment: You can get help from the following tutorial. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeMtmkDZ72Q This tutorial explains how the session authentication data stored in cookie.

Comment: Please mark this answer as right if you found my response helpful for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is not suitable for me. As I wrote above, I need an auth solution to protect my webroutes and api routes. Laravel Sanctum is suitable for SPAs but not for my case.

Comment: I think this might help you find your solution. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#protecting-routes